# Auto insert area code

Tags: ms-access

I have a text box in Microsoft Access 2013 that corresponds to a telephone number.  The text box has the input mask of:

```
!\(999") "000\-0000;;_
```

I am trying to auto insert the area code.  For example, when a users goes to enter a telephone number, the area code is already populated into the text box.  I have tried to set the default value in both the table design and on the property sheet of the text box but no luck.  Its always aligned to the right. For example it looks like this:

[image]

If I add spaces to the default value on the text box property, the input mask is ignored and Microsoft Access generates an error stating:

> The value you entered isn't appropriate for the input mask '!(999") "000-0000;;_' specified for this field.

I have contemplated modifying the table structure to include a specific field for an area code, but that is my last resort.

Is there a more efficient way to automatically populate the area code in the text box when a new record is generated?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function in VBA to do this. Something like;

```
Function FormatPhone(PhoneNumber As String) As String

    FormatPhone = "(719)" & PhoneNumber

End Function
```

This function will take a string like '123-4567' and return '(719)123-4567'.

In the AfterUpdate event of your phone number field put;

```
[TextBoxControlName].Value = FormatPhone(Nz([TextBoxControlName].Value,""))
```

and this will add the formatted string to the text box.